# Timer doesnt work as expected since it ends the program instantly

Tags: java, timer

So I would like to make a program which opens the "Never Gonna Give You Up" every n-seconds. For this I implemented a Timer. Since I dont have alot of experience, It doesnt work (No output and finishes instantly with exit code 0).

Thanks in advance

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

    public class Rickroll implements ActionListener {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
         Rickroll r = new Rickroll();
         r.startTimer();
        }
        public void startTimer()
        {
            new Timer(2000, this).start();
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            try {
                desktop.browse(new URL("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstleyVEVO").toURI());
            } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException i) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are using is a [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), which should be used to update and/or change Swing-components, meaning they should not be used in this instance.

You could however use a [`java.util.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), or a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to perform this task. While `Timer` are easier to understand, a `ScheduledExecutorService` gives you more freedom in scheduling tasks. AFAIK, `ScheduledExecutorService`s are more resilient to `Runtime Exception`s, so there's another upside to using them.

The implementation of both would look like this:

`java.util.Timer`:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Rickroll {
  private static Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    
    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        openVideo();
      }
    }, 0, n * 1000);
  }
  
  private static void openVideo() {
    try {
      desktop.browse(new URL("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstleyVEVO").toURI());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      exc.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

`ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Rickroll {
  private static Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 10;
    
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> openVideo(), 0, n, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
  
  private static void openVideo() {
    try {
      desktop.browse(new URL("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&ab_channel=RickAstleyVEVO").toURI());
    } catch (Exception exc) {
      exc.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to create timer in java. You can move your logic inside run method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Action invoked by every seconds");
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```